# No funciona paralax en smartphone

Tags: html, css, responsive

tengo un problema con el paralax de un proyecto, en ResponsivelyApp se ve bien en todos los dispositivos pero en el smartphone real no se visualiza correctamente. Limpio caches y sigue igual, lo que mas extraño me parece es que hay gente que lo visualiza bien.
Paso imagen de como lo veo yo en mi smartphone, Iphone 12 IOS 16x
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.paralax__seccion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 8px solid rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.575);
  border-bottom: 8px solid rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.575);
  background: url(/img/background4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.paralax {
  display: grid;
  width: 120rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
 
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .paralax {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 2fr);
  }
}
.paralax__item {
  margin: 1rem 1rem;
  background: rgba(186, 182, 182, 0.595);
  border: 2px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.525);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
}
.paralax__item p {
  color: var(--negro);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: var(--roboto);
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px var(--negro);
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="paralax__seccion">
        <div class="paralax">
            <div class="paralax__item">                
                <p>De vez en cuando, la vida te ofrece grandes momentos. Montar en moto es uno de ellos.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="paralax__item">

                <p>Cuando estés triste recuerda que tienes una moto. Con eso basta para ser feliz.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="paralax__item">

                <p>Rueda bien, rueda libre, rueda seguro.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="paralax__item">

                <p>El amor por las motos es como el viento en la cara, no se ve pero se siente.
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Tambien dejo enlace a la pagina por si se quiere ver en vivo.
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://moteros-valencia.netlify.app/)

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Este sitio es de código en formato texto y no de enlaces y/o imagenes. Considera crear un [mcve]. Dado que usas HTML, CSS y Javascript, puedes usar un snippet del sitio. Poner un enlace a una web, que no sea relevante para el desarrollo (documentación, fiddler o similares) puede ser tomado como una estrategia de tu parte para recbir visitas a tu web, como estartegia SEO, por ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: Puedes describir el problema? a mí se me ejecuta el parallax cuando lo veo en modo móvil.

Comment: _No comparto codigo por que lo pueden ver en vivo_... Podemos verlo en vivo justo ahora, pero imagina que en dos meses eliminas la publicación y otro usuario tiene un problema similar, viene a consultar y trata de acceder al enlace... Se va a llevar la sorpresa de que no puede acceder. Tu pregunta dejaría de ser útil para futuros visitantes. Te sugiero seguir los enlaces que te dejó @MauricioContreras

Comment: Vale gracias, edite el mensaje, espero que este bien asi.